# can I compute the product of these two multivariate normal densities in a simple way

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution, variance, mean

I have two multivariate normal densities and I parameterise them by the *precision* matrix (i.e. the inverse covariance matrix). One of them has a sparse precision matrix and the other one has a simple precision matrix form with non-zero elements only along the diagonal matrix. So, we have as follows:

$$
A = N(\mu_1, \Sigma_1) \\
B = N(\mu_2, \Sigma_2)
$$

the $\Sigma$'s are the precision matrices. Now I can compute a new MVN density as the product of these two with the new precision $\Sigma$ as:

$$
\Sigma = \Sigma_1 + \Sigma_2
$$

So, the precisions can just be added. However, to compute the mean of this new Gaussian, I need to invert $\Sigma$, which is problematic because it is quite sparse.

My question is that considering one of the matrices is a diagonal matrix, is there some simplification/trick I can use to compute the mean of the new Gaussian density.

Also, to compute the normalisation of this new density, is it simply:

$$
Z = \frac{det(\Sigma)^{\frac{1}{2}}}{2\pi^{\frac{n}{2}}}
$$

where $n$ is the number of components in the MVN.

Comment: You seem to equate "the mean of this new matrix" with "the mean of the new Gaussian," but they have nothing to do with each other.  What do you really need to accomplish?

Comment: Sorry that was the type. I meant mean of the new Gaussian distribution.

Comment: I am trying to compute the new Gaussian which is going to be the product of two Gaussians. One of them has a sparse precision matrix associated with it and the other has even more sparse (diagonal) precision matrix. I wanted to know if there was a way to compute the mean and precision of the new Gaussian without inverting the sparse precision matrix.

Comment: Just to be totally clear (I don't think you have this confusion, but many do, so let's make sure it's clear for everyone) - when you say 'product of densities' you really do mean, as you say, the product of the densities of the random variables ($f(A)\,f(B)$), not the density of the product of the random variables ($f(A\,B)$), right?

Comment: Yes, I understand that the density of the product of 2 random variables is not necessarily normally distributed (even though the distribution associated with each RV might be normally distributed). No, I simply want to compute the product of 2 Gaussian distributions.

Comment: Also, I understand how it can be done (it is described in the matrix cookbook, for example) but I was wondering if there is a way to do it without involving inverting the precision matrices (taking advantage of the simple structure of one of the precision matrices, for example).